# Clipping multiple raster with multiple shapefiles in Python

Tags: python, raster, clip, fiona, subset

I am trying to adopt existing code for clipping multiple rasters with multiple polygons based on this link:

[Subsetting multiple rasters with multiple shapefiles using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382783/subsetting-multiple-rasters-with-multiple-shapefiles-using-python)

I added the following codes to create the shp_list, shp_names, raster_list, and raster_names.

It is supposed to clip raster by 128x128 dimension, but it is now 129x129. It seems the code changed the float N, S, E , and W to integers. In addition, the output is saved in the main directory not the results folder.
How can I modify the code to result the correct dimension (128x128) and save the clipping of each shapefile into separate folder?

```
def subs(shp_list, shp_names, raster_list, raster_names, outpath):
    for i, shp in enumerate(shp_list):
        with fiona.open(shp, "r") as shapefile:
            shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

            for j, ras in enumerate(raster_list):
                for scene in raster_list:
                    with rasterio.open(ras, "r") as src:
                        out_image, out_transform = mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
                        out_meta = src.meta

                        out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                                         "height": out_image.shape[1],
                                         "width": out_image.shape[2],
                                         "transform": out_transform})
                                         
                        ras_path = f"{outpath}{raster_names[j]}{shp_names[i]}{ras_extension[1:]}"

                        with rasterio.open(ras_path, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
                            dest.write(out_image)

    # number of created subsets
    subset_count = (i+1) * (j+1)
    if len(shp_list) * len(raster_list) == subset_count:
        print(f"Done. \n{subset_count} subsets created")

# calling the function
subs(shp_list, shp_names, raster_list, raster_names, result)
```